# Should webhook JSON payloads be URL encoded?

Tags: json, encoding, webhooks

New Relic currently URL encodes the JSON payload of our webhooks. We correctly include the necessary header, however, I'm wondering if this is best practice - or if the JSON payload should be sent un-encoded (or even with some different encoding)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more common to send JSON directly in the request body with a `Content-Type` header value of `application/json`. It's not entirely uncommon to do it the way New Relic does however. GitHub post-receive hook payloads are also encoded this way.

In some languages/frameworks it's easier to extract the JSON data from a parameter than from reading the entire request body since form parameters are automatically parsed out and easily referenced and in some cases reading a request body may involve some more elaborate stream parsing.

An example of that is PHP's syntax for extracting the entire raw request body:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

Versus extracting from a form parameter:

```
$data = $_POST["payload"];
var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

For frameworks that easily expose the request body, this isn't as much an issue. Here's the example given from the GitHub docs for handling the hook with Sinatra:

```
post '/' do
  push = JSON.parse(params[:payload])
  "I got some JSON: #{push.inspect}"
end
```

If the JSON body were passed directly, this is what it would look like:

```
post '/' do
  push = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  "I got some JSON: #{push.inspect}"
end
```

It's mostly just an aesthetic preference, there's no technical advantage to either. With the parameter, you do get the flexibility of sending multiple JSON payloads in a single request or the option to send additional meta data outside the JSON. I would suggest sending a list of JSON objects and including all the meta data in a top level wrapper if that's important to you. Something like this:

```
{
    "notification_id": "akjfd8",
    "events": [ ... ]
}
```

I personally prefer raw JSON bodies, but that's mostly because it makes debugging far easier on sites like RequestBin. Your screenshot does a great job of illustrating how unreadable JSON encoded into a form parameter is.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I was perplexed why Github sends it this way too. I seem to recall that before December 2012, it was not this way, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`<rant>`

Payloads should be the content type you say they are. If they are sending as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then that is what you should expect to find. The culture of using a Russian doll model of nested encodings is beyond stupid in my opinion.

If you want to send JSON send it as `application/json`. Is that really so hard?

`</rant>`